# How do I maintain same website layout at all zooms and browsers?

Tags: html, css, layout

I am very new to web designing and my site is almost about to be live. [http://cloudchowk.com/future/](http://cloudchowk.com/future)
But I have some serious issues found at the very last moment. When my site is zoomed in or out, the contents are being misaligned at some certain percentage of zoom. 
Also my footer gets misaligned to its left when viewed normally in iPad and iPhone.
I think firebug and chrome inspector will help you if you need my code because I don't know what code to insert here specifically.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Floating elements seems to be the root of the problem.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs Can you still narrow your help/suggestion please? I'm not sure of what to edit. Thanks

Comment: The problem is that the floating elements move down to the next available space when there is not enough room on the row it is currently on. I do not really know what you could do to fix it, but reducing the padding on the content boxes works around the problem.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs I tried a handful of CSS properties including the float and clear in some combinations. But no luck. Anyways Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that for all possible browsers / devices.

There is no programmatic way to lock your site so that no browser will be able to zoom it.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I think my question is not clear enough. If you can take a look at my site and zoom to the maximum , you might understand. The problem is with some CSS property I suppose, that too only when zoomed. Thanks for coming forward to help!